# How to chnage the color of a fillRect in canvas when you press a button?

Tags: javascript, canvas, onclick

I want to change fillRect size when I click a button outside of canvas something like this
Onclick="document.canvas.get context('2d').fillRect(0,0,100,100)"
so that a fillRect(100,100,100,100) will now be (0,0,100,100)
Thanks PS don't bring up spelling ect its not that

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this for example?

If so the main thing to look into would be [`clearRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) and [`fillStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle='blue';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<button>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit more sophisticated example but I hope it will not only fit your particular need but also show you some other possible ways to progress with your solution. I've introduced one thing. The rectangle is responsible for managing its state based on iteration and injected canvas (properties). When you click the "Action" button the rectangle just visits every corner of the canvas and changes its size in cycles (it first shrinks, then grows, and then shrinks and so on...). The code contains just basic checks against improper rect sizes. Enjoy.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('btnAction');
const canvas = document.getElementById('cnv');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const rect = {
  size: 210,
  delta: -10,
  iteration: 0,
  getState: function getState(canvas) {
  
    this.size += this.delta;
    
    if (this.size <= 0) {
      this.size = 0;
      this.delta = 10;
    }
    
    if (this.size >= canvas.width) {
      this.size = canvas.width;
      this.delta = -10;
    }
    
    const corner = this.iteration % 4;
    
    switch (corner) {
      case 0:
        return [0, 0, this.size, this.size];
      break;
      case 1:
        return [canvas.width - this.size, 0, this.size, this.size];
      break;
      case 2:
        return [canvas.width - this.size, canvas.height - this.size, this.size, this.size];
      break;
      case 3:
        return [0, canvas.height - this.size, this.size, this.size];
      break;
    }
    
  }
}

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(...rect.getState(canvas));

button.addEventListener('click', () => {

  rect.iteration++;
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(...rect.getState(canvas));
  
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="cnv" width="250px" height="250px"></canvas>
  <button id="btnAction">Action</button>
</div>
```